# How to disable wlan0 when shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, shutdown

Since a long time ago my Sony Vaio with Lubuntu 11.10 is showing a red FAIL message during the shutdown process.

It tries to kill some process and the white messages on the screen frozen for some seconds (a little pause) and then the FAIL appears and the shutdown goes on.

But it was not like this when I'd installed Lubuntu. Something happened and I didn't know until last week.

Last week I discovered why it is pausing the shutdown process for a while.

I disabled the wireless adaptor using the button in front of my laptop (that is, the hardware was off). Then I noticed that the shutdown was so quickly. No FAIL messages and my laptop was off after maybe 5 or 6 seconds.

So I'm almost sure that some wlan0 connection is holding the shutdown process. Maybe it is trying to keep connected or trying to disable the connection.

If I disable it using the button, everything is fast.

Any idea to fix this?

---

**Edit:** following the suggestion given by @Gilles, now the shutdown process is very fast. I used his script with the additional line `rfkill block all`.

But, as we can see on the image below, the script is returning some `not found`.

[image]

Comment: how about if you soft shutdown wlan0 before shutting down system... does it still take long ?

Comment: @Salton, are you talking about using the network icon on the panel to disable the wifi connection? I'd never imagined it. If it'll work, what would be your suggestion? I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: What messages appear before `FAIL`?

Comment: @Gilles, I recorded using a camera and I can see that when I press `esc` to show the messages I can read `Asking all remaining process to terminate... [OK]` and below `killing all remaining process... [FAIL]`. Also, something about `dispatcher`. Sorry but the camera unfocused so I'll need to record again today.

Comment: Thanks. That's weird, and hard to diagnose as it's happening after logging stops. Right now I have no idea what might be causing this.

Answer (score 3):

The message “killing all remaining process...” comes from the shutdown script `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`, which is executed as part of the shutdown sequence through the symbolic link `/etc/rc0.d/S20sendsigs`.

You can execute a custom script beforehand by linking it in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` (`0` for shutdown, `6` for reboot — don't ask) and giving it a priority less than 20. Write the following script as `/etc/init.d/sigur-wlan-stop`:

```
#!/bin/sh
## Turn off all wireless networks
for x in /sys/class/net/*; do
  if [ -e "$x/wireless" ]; then
    if grep -q "^$x=" /run/network/ifstate; then ifdown "${x##*/}"; fi
    ifconfig "${x##*/}" down
  fi
done
```

Make the script executable and link it in the shutdown scripts:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/sigur-wlan-stop
ln -s ../init.d/sigur-wlan-stop /etc/rc0.d/S10sigur-wlan-stop
ln -s ../init.d/sigur-wlan-stop /etc/rc6.d/S10sigur-wlan-stop
```

Comment: Ow, I wont ask... lol Thanks so much, I'll try this as soon as possible. Just to inform, if I disconnect the wlan0 using the icon on the panel, not the hard button, the problem remains. So it is something related with the hardware, I guess.

Comment: @Sigur Oh. Then after the `ifconfig` line, I think you'll need to add `rfkill block wlan`, or maybe `rfkill block wifi` or `rfkill block all`. If you're unlucky and you're hitting some weird firmware bug even that might not work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious to see the result of your script. I don't understand all those lines but `/run/network/ifstate` should be a path on my disc? Here on my pc (not the vaio) I don't have `/run` folder.

Comment: @Sigur `/run` is a recent-ish addition, not all distributions have it yet. I checked on Ubuntu 12.04, on older released maybe it's `/var/run/network`. If you don't have it, try going directly for `ifconfig … down` or even directly to `rfkill`. `ifdown` runs disconnect hooks, but when you're shutting down that rarely matters.

Comment: please, see my edited post. Now, it is very fast but some error appears.

Comment: @Sigur Either install the rfkill package, or (since you don't need it after all) don't put the `rfkill` line.

Comment: I tried without the `rfkill` line first. It does not work. So I added that line and tried again and then it works, but with that msg. Now I'd just installed the package. Is there some brutal force on the script? Is there some risk using that? The shutdown is so fast!

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated.  Use `ip link set wlan0 down` instead.

Comment: @BatchyX *Sigh* No, there is no reason not to use `ifconfig`. Just because the author of `ip` doesn't like `ifconfig` doesn't mean the rest of the world has to stop using it. `ifconfig` is present on far more machines and does it job adequately.

Comment: @Sigur The behavior you describe is really weird. Are you sure it's reproducible?

Comment: @Gilles: The authors of `ip` are Linux kernel maintainers. When they tell you `ifconfig` and its `ioctl`s are completely obsolete, they really mean it.

Comment: @Gille, Should I restart the system after the script was created? Would it work only after the second shutdown? If this was the case, so maybe this is the reason. 1. I created the script; 2. turn off the system and no result; 3. turn on the system and edited the script; 4. turn off the system and it works but with that `found` error.

Comment: @Gilles, it is not working. I don't know why but it worked only one time. Now I'm using the script with those 3 lines with `rfkill` but the problem remains. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to automatically turn off the wireless device *before* shut down, I would recommend putting

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

in your ~/.bash_logout file, that way it will be brought down during logout and you don't have to worry about the correct run levels within the rc files, resulting in a fast shutdown sequence.

If you get prompted for your sudo password, you can also do

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

and add

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to the end of the file (where username is your username) which will allow you to use sudo without prompting for a password every time, and thus allow you to disable your wireless connection right before the shutdown sequence begins  without a password prompt.

Comment: Just one question: if I need to use the `sudoers` approach, the pass for `sudo` commands will never be necessary? All the terminal commands will be executed without `root` pass requesting? This is not desirable.

Comment: @Sigur `.bash_logout` is the wrong place for this. It's only used in text mode sessions, so it won't be executed if you log out from the GUI, but it will be executed when you log out from an SSH session, which is exactly backwards.

Comment: All terminal commands you issue with _sudo_ won't ask for a password, but you can still use it as an access limiter.

@Gilles my mistake on bash_logout, I thought it occurred when the system began shutdown sequence and you were logged out. My mistake.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the explanation. I noticed that it didn't work. I discovered that LXDE has a file `autostart` to be used when the session starts. Is there a kind of `autoend`?

Comment: @Sigur, lxsession-logout is the closest equivalent script.

Comment: @JacobColeman, where is this file? I don't find it.

Comment: @Sigur If it doesn't exist you can create it and put it in /usr/bin/lxsession-logout which will then be called anytime you logout. :)

Comment: I found it on `/usr/bin`. But it is not a script file.